# BigQuery data transfer service for Google Play specific App data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-play

Can Google BigQuery data transfer service allow me to transfer specific app data automatically?

For example, I have 10 apps in my Google play console, I only want to transfer to BQ within only 3 apps. Is it possible to make this work or any approach?

Also, I just read the price of [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/pricing), The monthly charge is $25 per unique Package Name in the Installs_country table.

I don't quite understand how to calculate my cost with that example.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Tim Chiang, You can try downloading the [reports](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#reviews&zippy=%2Creviews) in Cloud Storage by selecting a specific app and then sending it to BigQuery using BigQuery Data Transfer Service. For the cost calculation of Google Play, it is calculated as $25 per month per unique package and stored in the Installs_country table in BigQuery. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi  @ShipraSarkar, if I gsutil cp the report from that bucket to my personal bucket and then transfer it to BQ, does it calculate with no charge, or does it still count that rule ($25 per unique package.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can download the [reports](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#reviews&zippy=%2Creviews) in Cloud Storage of a specific app by selecting the app from Google Play Store for which you want to get the data and then send it to BigQuery using BigQuery Data Transfer Service. The cost calculation of Google Play, it is calculated as $25 per month per unique package and stored in the Installs_country table in BigQuery.
For selecting the specific app, follow the steps given below :

- Go to the Play Console.
- Click on Download Reports and select the type of report you want.
- Under "Select an application," type and select the app for which you want to get the data.
- Select the year and month for which you want to download the report.

If you are storing data in a Cloud Storage bucket then that will incur cost and the pricing for data transfer from one storage bucket to another storage bucket can be checked in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/pricing) and since you are storing and querying in BigQuery that will also be chargeable.For BigQuery pricing details you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing). You can use the [Billing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to calculate your costs.